# #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'fx_users'

Tags: mysql

Here I am getting error like this, `#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'fx_users'`.

Where am I stuck?

**Thats my query:**

```
SELECT from_date
    , to_date
    , fx_users.username
    , fx_leave_type.NAME
    , STATUS
FROM fx_leave_assign
INNER JOIN fx_leave_type
    ON fx_leave_type.id = fx_leave_assign.leavetype_id
INNER JOIN fx_users
    ON fx_users.id = fx_leave_assign.user_id
INNER JOIN fx_users_attendance
    ON fx_users_attendance.user_id = fx_users.id
INNER JOIN `fx_account_details`
    ON fx_account_details.user_id = fx_users_attendance.user_id
INNER JOIN `fx_departments`
    ON fx_departments.deptid = fx_account_details.department
INNER JOIN `fx_users`
    ON fx_users.id = fx_users_attendance.user_id
WHERE fx_departments.deptid IN (1)
    AND fx_users.id IN (5)
    AND DATE (fx_users_attendance.clock_in) >= "2015-09-01"
    AND DATE (fx_users_attendance.clock_in) <= "2015-09-30"
    AND fx_leave_assign.leavetype_id = "1";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason is very simple, in your query you join to `fx_users` twice. You need to add aliases to them.

```
SELECT from_date,
       to_date,
       fu1.username,
       fx_leave_type.name,
       STATUS
FROM fx_leave_assign
JOIN fx_leave_type ON fx_leave_type.id = fx_leave_assign.leavetype_id
JOIN fx_users AS fu1 ON fu1.id = fx_leave_assign.user_id
JOIN fx_users_attendance ON fx_users_attendance.user_id=fu1.id
JOIN `fx_account_details` ON fx_account_details.user_id = fx_users_attendance.user_id
JOIN `fx_departments` ON fx_departments.deptid = fx_account_details.department
JOIN `fx_users` AS fu2 ON fu2.id = fx_users_attendance.user_id
WHERE fx_departments.deptid IN(1)
  AND fu1.id IN(5)
  AND date(fx_users_attendance.clock_in) >= "2015-09-01"
  AND date(fx_users_attendance.clock_in) <= "2015-09-30"
  AND fx_leave_assign.leavetype_id="1"
```

Also you should allias columnss `from_date`, `to_date` and `STATUS`. There are multiple tables and you can get ambiguous name.

Comment: Thanks @lad2025, I got your point but now it is giving error like, 
#1054 - Unknown column 'fx_users.id' in 'on clause' as I have this field in fx_users. So, what is the actual problem?

Comment: @ViralBhoot Updated `JOIN fx_users_attendance ON fx_users_attendance.user_id=fu1.id`

Comment: Omg...The silly mistake creates big...
Thank you so much...Its working now... :)

Comment: @ViralBhoot It happens,especially when you sit for many hours and stare at wall of text ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are joining the table `fx_users` twice. If you do so use different alias names for the table to allow the DB to distinguish between the two.

```
... JOIN `fx_users` as users_1 on ...
```